# How to efficiently produce a desired matrix in R?

Tags: r, function, matrix

I was trying to produce the following `7 x 4` matrix in R:

```
m = matrix(c(seq(25, 1, by = -4), 
             seq(26, 2, by = -4), 
             seq(27, 3, by = -4), 
             seq(28, 4, by = -4)), nrow = 7, ncol = 4)
```

**BUT,** I'm wondering if could I achieve the same matrix with more efficient R code than what I used above?

[image]

Comment: `matrix(1:28, 7, 4, TRUE)[7:1,]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
m <- matrix(rev(c(1:28)),nrow=7,ncol=4,byrow = TRUE)[,rev(1:4)]
```

And this one is even faster:

```
m <- matrix(28:1,nrow=7,ncol=4,byrow = TRUE)[,4:1]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
m = matrix(c(rep(seq(25, 1, by = -4),4) + rep(c(0:3),each=7) ), nrow = 7, ncol = 4)
```

Not sure if you would call this more efficient...